# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command while compiling

Tags: makefile, mingw32, jitsi-meet

Recently I exploring jitsi meet with the latest version, and I try to build the application.
But, after compiling makefile using make on Windows 10, I got an error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Here is error message while compiling:

```
> jitsi-meet-load-test@0.0.0 build
> webpack -p

[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of G:\Project\Digi46Meet\jitsi-meet-master\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Hash: e8ebfddcdcd744634d50
Version: webpack 4.43.0   
Child
    Hash: e8ebfddcdcd744634d50
    Time: 29243ms
    Built at: 02/22/2022 15:25:25
                            Asset     Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
     load-test-participant.min.js  221 KiB       0  [emitted]        load-test-participant
    load-test-participant.min.map  1.1 MiB       0  [emitted] [dev]  load-test-participant
    Entrypoint load-test-participant = load-test-participant.min.js load-test-participant.min.map
     [4] G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/logging/LogTransport.web.js 0 bytes {0} [built]
     [5] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 475 bytes {0} [built]
    [12] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
    [13] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 546 bytes {0} [built]
    [15] G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/lib-jitsi-meet/_.web.js 27 bytes {0} [built]
    [16] ./load-test-participant.js + 28 modules 83.2 KiB {0} [built]
         | ./load-test-participant.js 11.3 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/util/parseURLParams.js 1.68 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/util/uri.js 16.7 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/functions.web.js 2.21 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/lastn/functions.js 2.78 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/constants.js 1.21 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/util/helpers.js 5.59 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/util/strings.web.js 631 bytes [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/functions.any.js 8.73 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/video-quality/constants.js 755 bytes [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/util/index.js 178 bytes [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/configWhitelist.js 5.69 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/interfaceConfigWhitelist.js 1.42 KiB [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/logger.js 99 bytes [built]
         | G:/Project/Digi46Meet/jitsi-meet-master/react/features/base/config/getRoomName.js 389 bytes [built]
         |     + 14 hidden modules
        + 11 hidden modules
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:23: compile] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your makefile is invoking `cmd.exe` as the shell, and it's not able to parse the POSIX-style paths like `./...` that use forward slashes instead of backslashes as directory separators.

You'll either have to write your make recipes to use `cmd.exe` syntax, or else install a POSIX shell on your system somewhere that `make` can find it (or set the make `SHELL` variable to the path).